# Vagrant for Ruby on Rails: Error block in http_get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I've tried to set up a development environment for Ruby On Rails with Vagrant. I've followed [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development).

When I entered

```
vagrant up
```

It gave me this error

```
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "s3.amazonaws.com" port 443 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:354:in `block in http_get'
```

Followed by a bunch of message lines. I believed it was a firewall problem so I added firewall exceptions to vagrant.exe to allow all connections, didn't work.

Any ideas?

## Update

This is the complete log from the consol

```
> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: blog_default_1459892099282_67422
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> default: Auto-generating node name for Chef...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...    
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "s3.amazonaws.com" port 443 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:354:in `block in http_get'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:349:in `loop'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:349:in `http_get'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:238:in `cache_remote_object!'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:207:in `cache_version_uri_package!'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:216:in `cache_version_uri_unpacked!'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:93:in `block in version_uri_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:382:in `memo'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:92:in `version_uri_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:88:in `version_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:54:in `version_dependencies'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/site.rb:463:in `fetch_dependencies'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:125:in `fetch_dependencies!'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:117:in `fetched_dependencies'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:81:in `dependencies'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:117:in `block in check_manifest_for_cycles'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:117:in `each'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:117:in `map'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:117:in `check_manifest_for_cycles'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:64:in `block in recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:52:in `resolve_and_install_cookbooks'
            from C:/Users/JorgeAnzola/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:16:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:78:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:224:in `action_raw'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:199:in `block in action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:561:in `lock'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:185:in `call'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:185:in `action'
            from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: Were there any other lines? What is it trying to get from s3?

Comment: I'm gonna add the complete console message.

Comment: You might need to explain a bit more about the provisionning you're doing - seems you attempt to connect to `s3.amazonaws.com` - so first does your VM has access to internet ? also as you connect to s3, does the bucket you're trying to access allow download, any policy on the bucket that could prevent the VM to download from there